# Implement API query from Postman to React Native

Tags: react-native, postman

I have API method for get a list of tickets. When I try this method in postman (chrome extension), everything works good. When I try the same in react native, it has some issues with authorization — but I use the same token in both cases.

There is Postman query, which works correct:

```
var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "https://example.com/api/tickets/list",
  "method": "GET",
  "headers": {
    "authorization": "MzA4YTcwZjI2OGMMzNDhlZGVhYjUyNzQxNg==",
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
    "postman-token": "dc861781-6989-5707-d41f-ab52abda037d"
  }
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

And there is a react native fetch method with the same data, I reckon, but doesn't work correctly:

```
        var url = 'https://example.com/api/tickets/list';
        fetch(url, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'MzA4YTcwZjI2OGMMzNDhlZGVhYjUyNzQxNg==',
                'Cache-control': 'no-cache',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        })
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response);
            return response.json();
        })
        .then((responseData) => {
            var ticketList = responseData;
            console.log(ticketList);
            this.setState({
                dataSource: this.state.dataSource
                    .cloneWithRows(ticketList)
            });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Can you provide the error string?

Comment: 401, not authorized.

Answer (score 2):

It was because the `fetch` method replaced '**A**uthorization' with '**a**uthorization' (different case of first letter).